# VBScript xmlDoc Property name is invalid

Tags: vbscript

I have VBScript code below:

```
set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument")
xmlDoc.setProperty "NewParser", True
xmlDoc.async = false
```

I always get error saying that the "Property name is invalid" from this line: xmlDoc.setProperty "NewParser", True

Please let me know how can i fix this. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know nothing about XML but the docs say it requires XML4 while you are using XML2.

**NewParser**

Specifies whether to enable (true) or disable (false) the use of the new parser, which was introduced in MSXML 4.0, to load a DOM document. Setting the NewParser property to false causes subsequent DOM documents to be loaded using the old parser. Setting this property to true causes DOM documents to be loaded using the new parser.

This property is supported in MSXML 4.0, 5.0, and 6.0. The default value is false.

Script Syntax
  Copy Code 
domObj.setProperty(strProp, vBool);
vBool = domObj.getProperty(strProp);

Visual Basic Syntax
  Copy Code 
domObj.setProperty(strProp, vBool)
vBool = domObj.getProperty(strProp)

Comment: OP can use `set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0")` if available. That should do the trick.

Comment: `Msxml2` doesn't say anything about the DLL version. To use a specific XML library the version number must be appended to the object name (e.g. `Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0` for msxml4.dll). See [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269238) for an overview of XML parser versions released by Microsoft.

Comment: thank you for responding.  Yesterday I tried to install MSXML6.0 and the installer kept saying it's installed success but it installed so quick that I doubt it would get installed so I went to check Control Panel but I didn't see that MSXML6.0 in there.  But I installed successfully for MSXML4.0 Service Pack3.

Comment: I haven't tried XML4 yet but I did tried DOMDocument.6.0, but somehow it led into more error.  I will investigate tthese two suggestions again, thank you so much.

Comment: After I made change to use set xmlDoc = CreateObject("Msxml2.DOMDocument.6.0") , the error is gone, but I receive different error but not sure whether it's related to VBScript or the xml file that I drop onto the VBScript file because the error says that the xml file either empty or is not a well form xml.  But I verified the xml file by double clicking on it, and it's able to open on Internet Explorer.

Comment: @Bopha Please post a new question with the exact error code and message, the line that raises the error, and sample XML code to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Ansgar Wiechers, thanks for following up the question.  After changing to use Msxml2.DOMDocument.4.0 and then I use other people XML and XSL files that I found online, the VBScript is able to do what it's supposed to do.  So I think the format of the XML & XSL files that I used might be incorrect.